# How to get products with inventory greater than 0 and In Stock in Magento

Tags: magento, product, inventory

How to get products which inventory is greater than 0 and "In Stock" (inventory and In Stock attribute is set in Admin panel)

This is my current code

```
$_productCollection = $product->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
                                    ->setCurPage(1)
                                    ->setPageSize(12);
```

What condition should i add to get what i want?

Comment: By default, magento displays product which has inventory greater than zero and is set to "in stock". Other product won't display

Comment: So you mean that my code above will already retrieve only products with inventory greater than zero and is set to "in stock"?

Comment: if it helped you, accept it as answer. Othrewise post your own answer and feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know whether product is in stock or not, you can use `isInStock()`.

```
   $id = 24 //product id
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

   //check whether product is in stock
   if($_product->isInStock()){

       //do some stuff here
   }
```

You can display | hide products without inventory in front-end through admin.For this..

1. Go to `System ->Configuration`.
2. Select appropriate scope.
3. Select `inventory` tab under `CATALOG`
4. There you have an option to set this

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (which was about filtering a collection)